# terminal access and swap issue on lubuntu 16.04 install on HP mini 1000

Tags: boot, command-line, lubuntu, encryption, hp

My goal is to install an encrypted Lubuntu partition on my HP mini.

I am trying to install Lubuntu 16.04 i386 (downloaded direct from ubuntu.com), onto an HP mini 1000 (model 1116NR with 16GB harddrive). I am unable to access the terminal trying "ctrl-alt-f1", "ctrl-alt-f2", "ctrl-alt-t", to address the first error: a swap error due to security. When I try "ctrl-alt-f1", the screen goes blank except with a blinking cursor and I have left it on for up to an hour. I am able to return to the install screen by using "ctrl-alt-f1". I am able to access the terminal using the Lubuntu and Ubuntu 16.04 live CD.

Since I cannot access the terminal to use "swapoff -a" I tried installing after the error screen without encrypting the drive and receive a "ubi-partman failed with error code 141" error. I have to reboot and start over.

I have tried both YUMI and Linux Live CD creators for making the boot-able CD which is a flash drive as the HP mini has no CD player. I am able to install Lubuntu from either live CD so long as I don't try to encrypt the hard-drive.

I also cannot copy the error log since I do not have access to the terminal.

Please help!!!